# Missing Play! compiler error page, no data returned

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Migrated to Play! 2 and been hacking some code, but it's extremely difficult because every time I get a compiler error, I see this page in the browser:

[image: Chrome no data received]

Does anyone know the fix for this and why it would happen? Referencing this email thread looks like others are having trouble, too: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/Co9jFkmPYbA

### Update: eBean

After further investigation, eBeanPlugin is having trouble loading on every sample app and my own:

`play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin [Plugin [play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin] cannot been instantiated.]`

What's a possible fix?

Comment: I ran the app using `$ play` `$ run` which I thought put it in dev...is there a different way to run it in dev?

Comment: p.s. says `--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---`

Comment: Hm, my inexperience with Play 2 shows... sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve the problem. This particular distro of Play! was built from the GitHub repo. The steps I followed to get it working:

1. Cleaned Play! folder and made backup of project
2. Downloaded release binaries from http://www.playframework.org/download
3. Created a shiny new project `play new myapp`
4. Imported app, conf, and public folders

Was a pain to figure out, but I hope this helps someone in the future.